# Problem sending php variables to flash game, on facebook

Tags: php, database, flash, variables, flashvars

When I run the app for the first time in a session it works great i get all data form Database(if i logout, and enter with a diffrent account)the swf does not receive the variables. If i run manually the script typing the url address in the browser (typing: http://myserver.com/app/variables.php), and refresh the facebook app, it receives the data perfectly.How can i fix this?I used the URLVariables, URLRequest and flashvars but still with no succes.I asked for help on many forums but without succes, apparently there are many in my situation.Could this porblem be due the fact tha facebook does not allow flash to talk outside?
Any help would be highly apreciated!Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you are pulling the page twice and not running off a cached version (in browser or on server)? Try adding a var with the datetime stamp to force refresh.

"Www.somewhere.com/something.php?v=" + new date().getTime();

Comment: i have checked and i am not running off a cached version so that should not be the problem...any other suggestions?